# Pregunta para conocedores de Java y Visual Studio

Tags: java

Recientemente estoy empezando a trabajar con Java; realmente tengo mas experiencia con Visual Studio. Entonces, dado que los entornos son diferentes, me gustaría conocer cuáles son las equivalencias con Java:

- *Aplicaciones de escritorio*
  Con Visual Studio uso WinForms o WPF / ¿Con Java?
- *Aplicaciones de consola*
  Con Visual Studio uso Console Application / ¿Con Java?
- *Servicios Web*
  Con Visual Studio uso WebServices ASP o WCF / ¿Con Java?
- *Aplicaciones Web*
  Con Visual Studio uso ASP.Net o MVC / ¿Con Java?
- *Operaciones hacia bases de datos*
  Con Visual Studio uso ADO.NET/ EF / ¿Con Java?
- *IDE*
  Con Visual Studio, con Java hay varios ¿Cual me recomiendan?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Aplicaciones de escritorio Con Visual Studio uso WinForms o WPF / ¿Con
>   Java?

Java swing. Jpanel o Jframe dependiendo de lo que hagas

> Aplicaciones de consola Con Visual Studio uso Console Application /
>   ¿Con Java?

al hacer código sin interfaz las aplicaciones corren en consola lo puedes ver en la consola del IDE que uses, Tan simple como un hola mundo

> Servicios Web Con Visual Studio uso WebServices ASP o WCF / ¿Con Java?

Existen varias herramientas útiles la mas común es JSP,java server faces, y Frameworks como Spring o Play

> Aplicaciones Web Con Visual Studio uso ASP.Net o MVC / ¿Con Java?

La arquitectura tu la haces, Spring funciona en MVC pero es parte de tu paradigma de programación

> Operaciones hacia bases de datos Con Visual Studio uso ADO.NET/ EF /
>   ¿Con Java?

El mas común es Hibernate y te ayuda a la persistencia de datos, tamvien existe ODBC

Para IDE de .NEt siempre uso Visual Studio, con Java hay varios ¿Cual me recomiendan? Yo lo que aprendí fue con NetBeans, pero en muchos canales de educación usan Eclipse. en ambos puedes desarrollar aplicaciones de otros lenguajes incluso aplicaciones para dispositivos Móviles

Comment: Hola Fernando, 
Me gustaría saber si puedo arrastrar controles de usuario en Java como VS. Y Respecto a cualquier aplicación en genera con .Net se hace un ,exe, como puedo bacer apps indepdendientes en java? sabes?

Comment: Si, para eso tienes que usar la paleta. Si usas Netbeans solo dale en visualizar, paleta y hay encontraras los controles comunes como en visual Studio.  Referente a lo otro tienes que generar un JAR. creo que se genera solo y tienes que hacer un acceso directo para que se ejecute, como en cualquier aplicación de Visual Studio

Comment: Con eclipse se puede?

Comment: ME imagino que si, pero solo eh usado eclipse para aplicaciones móviles, pero me imagino que le descargas el completo de la paleta de controles

Answer (score 4):

He cambiado el orden de las preguntas para que facilite la lectura y comprensión.

> Aplicaciones de consola Con Visual Studio uso Console Application / ¿Con Java?

Las aplicaciones Java por defecto se ejecutan en una consola, independiente al tipo de aplicación que se cree. Para tus aplicaciones que serían netamente de consola, ejecútalas con el comando `java` y puedes utilizar `System.out.print`/`System.out.println` para imprimir mensajes de salida. Adicional a esto, existen frameworks como [clamshell-cli](https://github.com/vladimirvivien/clamshell-cli) y [Jansi](https://github.com/fusesource/jansi) que te facilitan el desarrollo y visualización de tus aplicaciones de consola hechas en Java.

> Aplicaciones de escritorio Con Visual Studio uso WinForms o WPF / ¿Con Java?

Existen varios frameworks en Java para crear aplicaciones de escritorio GUI. El más común es Swing, pero no es el único. Actualmente, Java 8 impulsa más el desarrollo con JavaFX y Swing se mantiene por compatibilidad. No existen componentes visuales para arrastrar en Java, esto dependerá del IDE y de plugins que tenga el IDE para soportar Swing, JavaFX u otros. Sin embargo, para JavaFX puedes crear tu GUI utilizando [Scene Builder](http://gluonhq.com/labs/scene-builder/). ¿Cuál de estos frameworks elegir? Dependerá de ti. De manera personal, recomiendo JavaFX sobre Swing (fuera del conocimiento y rechazo popular).

De la respuesta a la pregunta anterior, existe también el comando `javaw`, el cual no se utiliza una consola para mostrar la salida del programa. Resulta útil para ejecutar tus aplicaciones GUI.

> Aplicaciones Web Con Visual Studio uso ASP.Net o MVC / ¿Con Java?

Las aplicaciones web en Java usualmente siguen el estándar Java EE (Java Enterprise Edition). Estas aplicaciones se ejecutan sobre un servidor de aplicaciones que trabaja bajo este estándar o un grupo relevante de ellas. Principalmente, se utiliza JSP para la vista y Servlet como controladores (siguiendo el patrón MVC). Así mismo, existen frameworks construidos encima de estas tecnologías como JSF, Spring MVC, Struts 2, etc que facilitan el desarrollo de las aplicaciones web.

> Servicios Web Con Visual Studio uso WebServices ASP o WCF / ¿Con Java?

Cualquier aplicación web puede proveer servicios web. Existen dos estándares principales para proveer servicios: JAX-WS para servicios web sobre SOAP y JAX-RS para servicios web estilo REST. Estos estándares están implementados por frameworks particulares a cada uno, siendo [metro](https://metro.java.net/) y [jersey](https://jersey.java.net/) las implementaciones de cada estándar respectivamente. Sobre ello, existen frameworks como Spring WS y Spring REST que proveen otra forma de implementar este tipo de servicios.

En Java, no existe un símil directo a WCF. Existen productos como un ESB que pueden realizar lo que solicitas y mucho más. A lo mucho, si quieres algo menor a un ESB y con mayor poder que WCF pues tienes [Apache Camel](http://camel.apache.org/).

> Operaciones hacia bases de datos Con Visual Studio uso ADO.NET/ EF / ¿Con Java?

Las operaciones a base de datos con Java se realizan mediante JDBC. Todos los frameworks de conexión a base de datos en Java están escritos como una capa superior a JDBC.

Un equivalente en Java para EF sería JPA. Este es un estándar de comunicación hacia la base de datos basado en frameworks ORM. Entre las implementaciones más populares de JPA se encuentran [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/) y [EclipseLink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/). Si no necesitas trabajar con un framework ORM, puedes utilizar otras opciones como [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) o [jOOq](http://www.jooq.org/), entre otros.

> Para IDE de .NEt siempre uso Visual Studio, con Java hay varios ¿Cual me recomiendan?

Deberías utilizar el IDE que más se adecúe a tus necesidades y gustos. Los más populares actualmente son [IntelliJ IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) (tiene versión comunitaria que es libre, la oficial es pagada), [Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/) y [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/), y luego otros como [BlueJ](http://www.bluej.org/) que no ofrecen tantas funcionalidades como los mencionados anteriormente. Yo he trabajado con los tres, y me siento cómodo tanto con Idea como con Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

Para desarrollar en Java existen varias opciones **[NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/)**, **[Intellij IDEA](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/)**, **[Eclipse](https://eclipse.org/downloads/)**, etc...

> - Para WinForms el equivalente puede ser [Swing](https://netbeans.org/features/java/swing.html) para construir GUI.
> - Console Application simplemente crea tu aplicación tipo Console.
> - Application. WebServices ASP o WCF la versión Java sería [Java Server    Pages](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/jsp/index.html).
> - Visual Studio uso ADO.NET Java con el framework [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) (existe más)    y [ODBC](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jdbc/bridge.html).

Cada IDE tiene sus puntos positivos y negativos, personalmente he usado NetBeans, Intellij IDEA y Eclipse, actualmente (desde hace 2 años) uso principalmente NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

pues para el trabajo de java uno de los IDE más utilizados es netBeans, a mi personalmente me gusta bastante, también esta IntellijIdea que facilita bastante la cuestión, depende de ti probar y decidir cual es el mejor según tus gustos.

Por cierto creo que de NetBeans se encuentra más documentación en la web.

Answer (score 1):

Para desarrollo de aplicaciones web hecha un vistazo a [Java Server Faces (JSF)](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/javaserverfaces-139869.html).

Es común utilizar éste framework junto con otros de componentes UI, como pueden ser:

- [RichFaces](http://richfaces.jboss.org/)
- [PrimeFaces](http://primefaces.org/)
- [OmniFaces](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/)
- [IceFaces](http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEfaces/overview.jsf)
- [OpenFaces](http://openfaces.org/)

Añado este [tutorial de Mkyong](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/jsf-2-0-tutorials/) que tiene un *quick start* para JSF bastante completo